# C# Type comparison using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, comparison

I'd like to check if a property is of type `DbSet<T>` using reflection.

```
public class Foo
{
    public DbSet<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}
```

By using reflection:

```
var types = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes();
foreach (var type in types)
{
    if (type.IsSubclassOf(typeof (Foo)) || type.FullName == typeof (Foo).FullName)
    {
        foreach (
            var prop in Type.GetType(type.FullName).
                GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Instance))
        {
            var propType = prop.PropertyType;
            bool a = propType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof (DbSet<>));
            bool b = typeof (DbSet<>).IsAssignableFrom(propType);

            bool c = propType.BaseType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof (DbSet<>));
            bool d = typeof (DbSet<>).IsAssignableFrom(propType.BaseType);


            bool e = typeof (DbSet<>).IsSubclassOf(propType);
            bool f = typeof (DbSet<>).IsSubclassOf(propType.BaseType);
            bool g = propType.IsSubclassOf(typeof (DbSet<>));
            bool h = propType.BaseType.IsSubclassOf(typeof (DbSet<>));

            bool i = propType.BaseType.Equals(typeof (DbSet<>));
            bool j = typeof (DbSet<>).Equals(propType.BaseType);

            bool k = propType.Name == typeof (DbSet<>).Name;
        }
    }
}
```

- Is there a merged solution to check the type? As you can see, I'm using `IsSubClassOf` + `FullName` to get classes of type `Foo` and any other class which is derived from `Foo`.
- all the checks (a to j) except c,f,k return false. c,f return System.Object as BaseType which is no use for me. k, I consider an *unsafe check*. But will be my what I use if no other workaround is found. In debug mode, the `propType`'s `FullName` is:

  ```
  System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1[[Console1.Bar, ConsoleApplication1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]
  ```

  Is there any other way to check if `propType` is of type `DbSet<>`?
  Thanks.

Comment: could you use the PropertyInfo.PropertyType here is a link to MS on that http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.propertytype.aspx

Comment: @DJKRAZE: `PropertyInfo.PropertyType` returns `System.Data.Entity.DbSet'1[[Console1.Bar,...`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you need it to cope with subclasses of `DbSet<>` as well? If not, you can use:

```
if (propType.IsGenericType &&
    propType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(DbSet<>))
```

Full sample:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

class Test<T>
{
    public List<int> ListInt32 { get; set; }
    public List<T> ListT { get; set; }
    public string Other { get; set; }
    public Action<string> OtherGeneric { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var query = from prop in typeof(Test<string>).GetProperties()
                    let propType = prop.PropertyType
                    where propType.IsGenericType &&
                          propType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>)
                    select prop.Name;

        foreach (string name in query)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(name);
        }
    }
}
```

With subclasses you'd just need to apply the same test recursively up the inheritance hierarchy. It becomes more of a pain if you need to test for interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is that it is assuming that `typeof(DbType<>)` denotes a regular type. It is not a normal type: rather, it is a generic type definition. That is why the  `IsAssignableFrom`, `IsSubclassOf` etc. are not going to work. `Type` `x` is of type `DbSet<T>` if the following condition is true:

```
x.IsGenericType && x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(DbSet<>) && x.GetGenericTypeArguments()[0] == typeof(T)
```

Comment: Thanks. But I couldn't find any `GetGenericTypeBase()` instance method. did you mean `GetGenericTypeDefinition()`?

Comment: @Kamyar Sorry, I meant `GetGenericTypeDefinition` (fixed).

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest the following type comparision (worked fine for me):

```
foreach (var prop in customObject.GetType().GetProperties().Where(e => e.CanRead && e.CanWrite))
{
    var typeName = prop.PropertyType.FullName ?? "";
    //!!! Type comparision here:
    if (typeName == typeof(string).FullName)
    {
        prop.SetValue(customObject, "abc");
        continue;
    }
    // other code
}
```

For nullable types (for example `DateTime?` ) you might use this type of comparison:

```
if (typeName.Contains(typeof(string).FullName))
{
    prop.SetValue(customObject, "abc");
}
```